# Stored procedure counting trouble

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table [users] that I wish to count the number of each occurrence of Movie_ID and update the record in a different table called [total]. So for Movie_ID=81212 it would send the value 2 to my [total] table.

like below:

```
        ------------------------------------
        |  [users]                          |   [total]
    +---------+---------+              +---------+-------------+
    |Movie_ID |Player_ID|              |Movie_ID | Player_Count|  
    +---------+---------+              +---------+-------------+
    |81212    |P3912    |              | 81212   |      2      |
    +---------+---------+              +---------+-------------+
    |12821    |P4851    |              | 12821   |      1      |
    +---------+---------+              +---------+-------------+
    |81212    |P5121    |
    +---------+---------+
(movie_ID + player_ID form composite key
so Movie_ID does not need to be unique)
```

---

So i'm trying to accomplish this with a stored procedure, this is what I have so far: I'm not sure how to code the part where it loops through every entry in the [users] table in order to find each occurrence of movie_id and sums it up.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `movie_total` (OUT movie_count int(5))
LANGUAGE SQL  
MODIFIES SQL DATA  
BEGIN

DECLARE movie_count int(5);

SELECT count(movie_id) AS movie_count FROM users 
foreach unique row in Users  ;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE movie_id) > 0 
    THEN
    INSERT INTO total (:movie_id, :Player_Count) VALUES (movie_id, movie_count);


 END //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update this field you can use a query like this -

```
UPDATE
  total t
  JOIN (SELECT Movie_ID, COUNT(*) cnt FROM users GROUP BY Movie_ID) m
    ON t.Movie_ID = m.Movie_ID
SET
  t.Player_Count = cnt
```

BUT: Do you really need a `total` table? You always can get this information using SELECT query; and the information in the `total` table may be out of date.

Comment: Well I plan to run the procedure on every update of the users table.

Comment: In this case you can use a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this without a loop:

```
update total set total.Player_Count = (select COUNT(Movie_ID) from users where total.Movie_ID=users.Movie_ID group by (Movie_ID));
```